# Will OnReceive in CAsyncSocket be interrupted by another OnReceive?

Tags: windows, mfc

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfttx1af.aspx) says that OnRecevie will be called by the framework to notify this socket that there is data in the buffer that can be retrieved by calling the Receive member function. What will happend if data can be retrived when a OnRecieve is running?

Answer (score 0):

The next `OnReceive()` wont be called in the middle because all processing is done in the same thread. Internally this is done via message pump in `CSocketWnd`. You can manually invoke `AsyncSelect()` at the end of `OnReceive()` if you believe there is another chunk of data on the way.

Answer (score 0):

After you call Receive winsock will post a new message to your message queue if more data is available. This will cause OnReceive to be called whenever your app resumes pumping messages. This would normally be after your return from OnReceive.

But there is an exception. If you pump messages (for example by calling MessageBox) before you have returned from OnReceive then OnReceive can be called while you are still in OnReceive. So don't pump messages!